# Batch file overseeing other programs?

Tags: file, batch-file

So i'm creating a text based game using batch files. And I was curious if its possible for a batch file to first off be non visible. to oversee another batch file, and one more program, and if either of the 2 programs its overlooking close, it closes the remaining one and itself?
I know its kind of complex. But I was thinking it would be a way to put music in my game.

Comment: No, yes, yes, and it's-complicated-but-yes.

Comment: Could you explain possibly? i'm a fast learner.

Answer (score 0):

### Hidden Windows

You can use Visual Basic Script to create hidden windows.

Just create a program called HiddenLaunch.vbs (or something) with the code

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & WScript.Arguments(0) & """", 0, False
```

...then launch it using

```
wscript.exe "C:\Wherever\HiddenLaunch.vbs" "C:\Some Other Place\MyBatchFile.bat"
```

or, if you need to pass arguments

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "" & WScript.Arguments(0) & "", 0, False
```

this will create a hidden batch window.

---

### Checking the process

Now you need to monitor another process, in this case you can use

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq myapp.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "myapp.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Programm is running
```

The %ERRORLEVEL% tells you if it couldn't find the program.

Happy coding!